# Assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Dashboard component

Tags: react-native, state

I'm passing a string value from one component class to another and try to update the state in another class

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    systemDetailsData: null,
   }
 }
   CalledFromHeader = (systemDetailsData11) => {
     this.setState({ systemDetailsData:systemDetailsData11 })
   }
 }



  class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Dashboard_Obj = new Dashboard();
     }

    OnPress = () => {
    Dashboard_Obj.CalledFromHeader("system data");
    }
   }
```

I'm getting this error ---> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Dashboard component.

I want to update the state in Dashboard class using above code, Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Call the `Header` component in `Dashboard` render method and pass a function as a prop to `Header` component.

```js
class Dashboard extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      systemDetailsData: null,
     }
   }
   CalledFromHeader = (systemDetailsData11) => {
     this.setState({ systemDetailsData:systemDetailsData11 })
   }
   
   redner(){
    return <Header changeState={this.CalledFromheader} />
   }
}



  class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    
    render(){
      return(
        // something view onPress handler
        <Button onPress={()=>{
          this.props.CalledFromHeader('Some parameters')
        }} />
      )
    }
 }
```